# How to use Session in 2 different controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I want to use a session in ASP.NET MVC but I think they're not connected. I have two different controllers and the `AccountController` seems fine because it's where I declared my session but I need to call it the `DashboardController` in order to prevent loading the login page again.

Here is the `AccountController`:

```
    SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader dr;

    // GET: Account
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        if (Session["user"] != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Home", "Dashboard", new { user = Session["user"].ToString()});
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    void connectionString()
    {
        SqlCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-94CAMNQ;Initial Catalog=QCUPasabuyDemoDb;Integrated Security=True;";
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Verify(tbl_user acc)
    {
        connectionString();
        SqlCon.Open();   

        SqlCom.Connection = SqlCon;
        SqlCom.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username='" + acc.username + "'AND password='" + acc.password + "'";

        dr = SqlCom.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            SqlCon.Close();
            Session["user"] = acc.username;
            return RedirectToAction("Home", "Dashboard");
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCon.Close();
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

While this is the `DashboardController`:

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    // GET: Dashboard
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        if (Session["user"] == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Home", "Dashboard", new { user = Session["user"].ToString() });
        }
    }

    public ActionResult home()
    {
        return View("");
    }

    public ActionResult services()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult about()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult logout()
    {
        String webuser = (String)Session["user"];
        Session.Abandon();
        return RedirectToAction("Login","Account");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no prohibition on this. Do you not receive session value on other controllers?

Comment: Side note: **please** look into SQL query parameterization and also don't store passwords in the db